# Need to add to some list elements from a range of values

Tags: python

We have this list with elements = 0
For example:

```
A = [0 for x in range (35)]
```

This list is filled with 35 zeros.

I have I have several list with ranges(about 5) from file with table to use:
Example:

```
15 20
20 3
12 5
5 1
7 22



for i in file:
    start_elem = min(i[0], i[1])
    end_elem = max(i[0], i[1]) #Here it takes the maximum and minimum values from the table from the file.
```

And I need that after each cycle "for" he adds units to my list, where I have zeros, by index, which are indicated in the cycle (start_elem, end_elem).
This option doesn't work:

```
for j in A[int(start_elem):int(end_elem)]:
     j+=1
     print(A)
```

The conclusion should be such like

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

My code is:

```
L = [0 for j in range (36)]
for i in file:

    start_elem = min(i[0], i[1])
    end_elem = max(i[0], i[1])

    for j in L[int(start_elem):int(end_elem)]:
        j+=1
        print(L)

        file_new.write(str(L))
gen_file.closed
gen_file_new.closed
```

Comment: Your min and max will not work : you should replace by min(i) and max(i)

Comment: @MatinaG the syntax of `min(i[0], i[1])` is not the problem, that will work as long as i is an iterable of numbers. But it does not fit to the loop `for i in file`, because that would indicate that i is firstly just a string. All in all a next question to be clarified btw...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify your task, what you have done so far and what's the problem with that. so jst for example: what do you mean by "unit" - the number 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Python list of lists is *not* a good choice of data structure for this problem, since you are updating values in Python-level nested loops. If you can use a 3rd party library, you can do this with NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

x = StringIO("""15 20
20 3
12 5
5 1
7 22""")

# define array of zeros
A = np.zeros(35)

# replace x with 'file.csv'; load and sort indices
index_array = np.sort(np.loadtxt(x, dtype=int), axis=1)

# iterate array of sorted indices
for start, end in index_array:
    A[start: end] += 1

array([ 0.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Comment: Produces the following error:"     for start, end in map(sorted, list_of_lists):
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1). " Maybe the problem is that the values that I want to use as a range are stored in a file that I convert to a list?

Comment: @PrapPrep, Probably. I mean, my code is *self-contained*, so the issue must be with how you are producing the list of lists (if at all).

Comment: Thank you. Can I clarify then how to correctly open the file that contains the table that is given in the question above. You wrote with a specific list, but how exactly do I open table from a file into such a list like yours?

Comment: @PrapPrep, If you're going to use NumPy, you can use `np.loadtxt` (see update)

Comment: I see. Then the last question. I apologize that I did not clarify the issue immediately.
If in the file I have a table of values, but those columns that I need are in column 3 and 4 for example. How can I take these columns 3 and 4, but not touch the others?

Comment: @PrapPrep, See [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), `np.loadtxt` has a `usecols` parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

To begin with , you should calculate your min and max correctly. Then consider the following:

```
for i in file:
    start_elem = min([i[0], i[1]])
    end_elem = max([i[0], i[1]]) 


    for j in range(int(start_elem):int(end_elem)):
        A[j]+=1
        print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

`j` is just a loop variable. Rebinding it will not affect `A`. Do instead:

```
A = [0 for x in range (35)]
file = [[15, 20], [20, 3], [12, 5], [5, 1], [7, 22]]

for i in file:
    start, end = sorted(i)
    for x in range(start, end):
        A[x] += 1  # rebind the actual list index
A
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```